# Overflow in exp when curve_fit of datetime

Tags: python, pandas, overflow, curve-fitting, exponential

I tried to fit datetime vs. float data using `curve_fit`. As far as I understand, curve_fit does not work with datetime, so I first have to convert the data to numerical values. This gives me very large values for x that cause an overflow in the exp function. My code is below. The same code does work if I fit with a polynomial instead of the exponential.

```
    def func(x, a):
        return (np.exp(a*x))

    def fit_exponential(gd):
        gdtemp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(gdtemp.Date)

        mask = (gdtemp['Date'] > '2020-01-30') & (gdtemp['Date'] <= '2020-03-20')

        gdtemp = gdtemp.loc[mask].copy()

        x = pd.to_numeric(gdtemp.Date)
        y=gdtemp['Confirmed']

        popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x, y)
```

How can I modify the code to work with the exponential?

---

I have two ideas on how to fix this but am not sure how to go about implementing this:

**1st idea:** Don't convert with to_numeric, but in some other way that produces smaller numbers. My input data is fairly simple and consists of exactly 1 row per day, so I don't need time or anything else. Is there another function similar to to_numeric() that ignores the time part and produces smaller numbers?

**2nd idea:** divide the numeric date values by some large number and later multiply back. What number should I use for dividing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, by mapping the large numerical x values to the interval [0;1] and fitting on this interval.

The essential modifications are:

```
small_x = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func4 ,small_x, y )
```

The values in the exponent are now reasonable (on the order of 1 in my case) and there is no problem with overflows.

Without this mapping I would end up with very large x values (on the order of 10^(15)) and very tiny values for a (on the order of 10^(-15)) which obviously the fititng function did not like.